# Failing to upload a CSV file thru a custom PHP uploader

Tags: php, html, csv

I was trying to make a very simple php uploader that uploads only one .CSV file and I need it to overwrite the one that is already on the server. I tried working with the upload part until I got it working. I have already setup 777 permissions in the upload directory, however I keep getting errors when uploading the file. The overwrite part I have not been able to code it yet and I may need a bit of help to make it. The .csv file is 1.5MB. The error that I get when uploading the file is the one saying that the file has the wrong extension, but I am 110% sure that the extension is .csv.

Here is the code:

upload.php

```
  <?php
  // Configuration - Your Options
  $allowed_filetypes = array('.csv',); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
  $max_filesize = 5000000; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 5MB).
  $upload_path = 'upload/'; // Upload directory

  $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
  $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.

   // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not a *.CSV file.');

   // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is larger than 5MB.');

   // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');
   ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="GET">
Update CSV File: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the upload part?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're checking for a `$_FILE` index with the value `userfile`, but your form is sending it in with a value of `uploaded_file`

```
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

should probably be

```
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
```

Comment: Well I tried that and still I am getting the error saying that the CSV is not an allowed extension

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following correction by changing 
 
method from GET to POST
Also since the name of file input is "uploaded_file". Also change

```
 $_FILES['userfile']['name'] to  $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
```

Should definitely work!

Comment: I made the changes and still is giving me the same issue.